# SSRS 2005 or 2008 Report Model Data Caching?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Whether in SSRS 2005 or 2008, someone said that SSRS Report Model will cache the data defined within the report model and you will be required to update the report model regularly to get the new data into the report model views...  is that correct?

To me, it seems the report mdoel stores the definition/metdata only... could someone verify?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to refresh or recreate the Model when the underlying objects are changed - For instance an underlying column is added or removed

This [document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/7/a/47a548b9-249e-484c-abd7-29f31282b04d/SSRS_ReportModel.doc) has a good overview of the model and explains that its only definition changes that require changes to the model itself

Comment: So you know for sure that you do not have to recreate the model to reload the data?  Someone from MS said you did have to, but wasn't sure.

Comment: @iain27 is correct. You can however, configure the report to cache results, but it has nothing to do with the model.